CANNOT find glew32.dll when I try to run connectome workbench_view in WINDOWS
I have downloaded connectome workbench_view from https://www.humanconnectome.org/software/get-connectome-workbench#download and unzip it. But when i try to run wb_view.exe, it says that CANNOT find glew32.dll.
How to slove this problem? Should i download something or add some address to my PATH?
